# Join across two many-to-many relations, 'all' operator

Tags: sql, join, many-to-many

I have four value tables: instructors, certifications, block_subjects and blocks and two relation tables: instructor_certifications and subject_certification. Like this:

```
block -- block_subject
          |
          |
 subject_certification
          |
          |
     certification 
          |
          |
instructor_certification
          |
          |
      instructor
```

I want a query that will tell me, *for every block*, which instructors are qualified to teach the block. Specifically, I don't want to specify the block id as part of the query; I want to select multiple blocks based on a different critera.

Here is the (non-working) query I currently have:

```
select inst.name, inst.id
from instructor as inst
join instructor_certification as ic on inst.id = ic.instructor_fid and
ic.certification_fid = all (
   select cert.id
   from block_subject as bs 
   join subject_certification as bsc on bsc.block_fid = bs.id
   join certification as cert on bsc.certification_fid = cert.id
   where bs.id = any (
       select bs.id
   from block as b
       join block_subject as bs on b.subject_fid = bs.id
       where (b.start_date, b.end_date) overlaps (?, ?)
   )
)
```

Obviously, this doesn't work because the 'all' collects all the certifications required for every block_subject in the date range.

Edit: Also I should have clarified that multiple certifications per block_subject are, in fact, required.

Comment: Sounds to me like the relational operator you require is [division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/): "the supplier who supplies all parts" -> "the teachers who can teach all subjects on the block", perhaps?

Comment: That does look like what I need ... Oh the joys of never having actually taken a database class.

Comment: ok I changed it to your new requirement.

Answer (score 1):

After the edit:

To require multiple certs per block per teacher:

```
 select b.id as blockid, bs.subject_id as subject_id, i.id as inscructorid, count(ic.certification_id) as numCerts
 from block b
 join block_subject bs on b.id = bs.block_id
 join subject_certification sc on bs.subject_id = sc.subject_id
 join instructor_certification ic on sc.certification_id = ic.certification_id
 join instructor i on ic.instructor_id = i.id
 group by b.id, bs.subject_id, i.id
 having count(ic.certification_id) > 1
```

---

Your problem states "For every block".  So, start with block and then do the joins.  Like so:

```
 select *
 from block b
 join block_subject bs on b.id = bs.block_id
 join subject_certification sc on bs.subject_id = sc.subject_id
 join instructor_certification ic on sc.certification_id = ic.certification_id
 join instructor i on ic.instructor_id = i.id
```

You can now add any criteria you want.

Specific block?

```
 where b.id = @inid
```

Date range?

```
 where @Date between b.start_date and b.end_date
```

Instructor?

```
 where i.id = @inid
```

Certification?

```
 where c.id = @inid
```

or a combination.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```
declare @Date datetime

set @Date = '01/01/2011'

select inst.name, inst.id
from instructor as inst
join instructor_certification as ic on inst.id = ic.instructor_fid 
and ic.certification_fid in (
   select cert.id
   from block_subject as bs 
   join subject_certification as bsc on bsc.block_fid = bs.id
   join certification as cert on bsc.certification_fid = cert.id
   where bs.id in (select bs.id 
       from block as b
       join block_subject as bs on b.subject_fid = bs.id
       where @Date between b.start_date and b.end_date ) )
   ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

just instructors...

```
 select
    i.*
 from
    instructor i on 
 where
    exists (
     select *
     from
        block b
        join block_subject bs on b.id = bs.block_id
        join subject_certification sc on bs.subject_id = sc.subject_id
        join instructor_certification ic on sc.certification_id = ic.certification_id
      WHERE 
        ic.instructor_id = i.id
        AND
        ..other filters here
        )
```